# Copy_from command to copy values of dictionary in a table

Tags: python

I want to insert values that are stored in a dictionary into a table. This dictionary contains  1000000 values.

The sample of my dictionary is :

```
 mydictationary: {"a":1; "b":2; "c":3; "d":4}
```

I am looking forward to use **copy_from** command (psycopg2) to copy these values into a table.
Something like:

```
cur.copy_from (mydictationary, myTable)
```

But is it possible to use copy_from command inorder to copy values from dictionary??? I want to use copy_from command as this might be faster than using sql insert statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normal way to do it:

```
cur.executemany('INSERT INTO myTable (key, value) VALUES (%s, %s)', mydictionary.items())
```

If you insist on using StringIO

```
import StringIO
dictFile = StringIO.StringIO()
for item in dictionary.iteritems():
    dictFile.write("%s\t%s\n"%item)
cur.copy_from(dictFile, 'myTable')
```

Comment: But can't we use copy_from command , as we used to do while copying data from stdin or from buffer?? something like: data = StringIO.StringIO() and then, copy_from(data, mytable), And also I got syntax error as, psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near ":"

Comment: that's because psycopg2 doesn't understand that style of arguments.